# What HTTP status to use in 2 factor authentication

Tags: http-status-codes, two-factor-authentication

My website workflow is that the user submits their username and password, then if 2 factor authentication is enabled, my website will request the user to enter 2 factor token via modal dialogue.

My question is what HTTP status code should I use to notify jQuery to prompt the user to enter the 2 factor token?

I'm thinking about `200 OK` but that could be misleading since it'll be the same as a successful login.
`100 Continue` can also be a candidate but it that won't comply with [RFC7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231) at all.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A `200` response in this case doesn't have to mean the same as the successful login. Reading the RFC and presuming you are `POST`ing the username and password, the `200` response should have a payload that is "a representation of the status of, or results obtained from, the action". Your payload should therefore be different based on whether a user has successfully logged in or only passed the first step of the process.

Comment: I went back and read the RFC again. And just like what you've said `200` work. Thanks.

Comment: not 100% on board with this. Modern API implementations that require another factor in their login process should return a different status code indicating auth is incomplete. At that point the user operates in an intermediary state with what is commonly known as a State Token. A 200 should be returned when you get the actual Session Token.

Comment: Do you have a proposal for what the status code response should be then?

Comment: @dwkd @philnash Though it's off RFC, I usually use `202 Accepted` described as "The HTTP 202 Accepted response status code indicates that the request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed". As login processing is awaiting confirmation, I think it makes sense to use it and it allows quick 2FA case detection.